# How to prevent inversion of color for nested Flyout in XAML?

Tags: xaml

My XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Show flyout">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Button"/>
                <Button Content="ShowSlider">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout>
                            <Slider Width="200"/>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

The nested Flyout appears with inverted color in the area intersected with the upper level Flyout:

[image]

How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of CommandBarFlyout works:

```
<Button Content="Show flyout">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Button"/>
                <Button Content="ShowSlider">
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <CommandBarFlyout>
                            <AppBarElementContainer>
                                <Slider Width="200"/>
                            </AppBarElementContainer>
                        </CommandBarFlyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```